# Streaming images from Windows to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, udp

I need to send live `depthimages` from a connected camera to an `iPhone`. The `image-getting` works fine but I've problems sending the array, which contains the pixelvalues as float. I'm using UDP to minimize the delay.
My intention is to split the float array into several chunks and display these chunks on the iPhone. I'm using `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` on the iPhone, but I don't understand the array cast from the received data on the `iPhone`.

Part of the code on Windows side:

```
 while ( true )
    {
    camera->requestImage();
    const float* floatImageData = cameraImage->getData(); 
    const char * charImageData = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(floatImageData);
    int total = 0;
    int byteCount = camera->width()*camera->height()*sizeof(floatImageData[0]);
    int bytesLeft = byteCount;
    int n;
    char buffer[8496];
    while(total < byteCount){
        memcpy(buffer,charImageData+total,8496);
        n = sendto(s,buffer,8496,0,(struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen);
        if (n == -1) {
            wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break; 
        }
        total += n;
        bytesLeft -= n;
        }
        std::cout << "sent : " << total << " should have : " << byteCount << std::endl;
        char input = '\0';
        std::cin.get(input);
        if ( 'q' == input )
            break;
    }
```

iPhone side:

```
-(void) addSocket{
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [udpSocket setMaxReceiveIPv4BufferSize:65535];
}
-(void) startSocket{

    int port = 8888;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"port blocked");
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"receive failed");
        [udpSocket close];

        return;
    }
}
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext{
    float* imageData = (float*)[data bytes];
    NSLog(@"received something, %d", data.length);
    NSLog(@"content: %f", imageData[10000]);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"receivedData" object:self];
}
```

I wanted to find out, how many elements the array contains, but got weird results. Therefore I wanted to access index 10000, which shouldn't exist because I send only 8496 bytes. But i get floats in the corresponding log and not the expected out of bounce exception. Why? When i increase the index (e.g. 100000) I get only 0.00000 as a result.